# Why LEFT OUTER JOIN is not working with @Query

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, h2, openjpa

I am using H2 DB and JPA. I have a below query with left outer join, but when I am printing the logs I cant see the "left outer join" part in the generated query and its not working.

```
@Query("select count(p) from Employee p left outer join Department d where " +           
            "p.id = d.eid"
 }
```

Generated Query Logs :

```
SELECT COUNT(p.ID) FROM EMPLOYEE p, DEPARTMENT d WHERE p.ID=d.EID
```

The "left outer join" is not there in the generated query and it's not working.

Anything I am missing, any suggestion would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're using Spring JPA because the @Query annotation doesn't exist in JPA specification.

You can either use the native syntax:

```
@Query("select count(p) from Employee p left outer join Department d on p.id = d.eid <where other filters>", 
    nativeQuery = true)
```

Or the JPQL syntax:

```java
@Query("select count(p) from Employee p left outer join p.department d <where other filters>")
```

Supposing the name of the association is `department` in `Employee` entity.

Worth noting that, in this query in specific, it doesn't make sense the join clause. If the idea is to count the number of employees - despite the situation of their relationship with a department, why to use the join at all? You would be better of using this query:

```java
@Query("select count(p) from Employee p")
```

Comment: There is some other intermediate logic, I want to count the number of employees based on logic along with the department and a few other tables.

Comment: @JDGuide So, did it work using JPQL? Another thing I noticed is that the query is using a `LEFT JOIN` but doesn't have an `ON` condition. Despite having the same effect for `INNER JOIN`, doing the matching in a `WHERE` clause can cause erroneous results in a `OUTER JOIN`.